# How do I show (and use) keyboard access keys in the Windows 11 Explorer new context menu?

Tags: windows-explorer, context-menu, windows-11

I just upgraded to Windows 11, and it looks like sometimes they use a new context menu when right-clicking items in Explorer -- at other times it shows the Win10 context menu, and I'm still not sure how it chooses which to use.

I've seen several questions about forcing it to always use the older context menu style.  I'm willing to try this newer one, so I don't need to do that, but I do need to always be able to use keyboard shortcuts to select a menu item.  I've enabled "Underline access keys" in the Accessibility -> Keyboard settings, and access keys are underlined in other places (like the Start menu Power User menu) but there don't appear to be any access keys for the new-style context menu.  Is that just an oversight, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything - at least in Windows 11 as it now exists. It may change in a year or so.

The new Context feature is itself (in part) context sensitive itself.

As an example, right click, copy and other things come up. If you select Copy and move to another folder, then Paste comes up as the likely context option.

I have spent time adapting to the new approach. I suggest you enter clear Feedback in the Windows 11 or General Feedback Hub. Microsoft is reviewing it all.

In direct answer to your question, you cannot natively structure your own particular context. Right now it is very hard wired.

Comment: I hope you're right about them actually paying attention to the Feedback Hub, because I see a lot of questions like mine where the answer is "it doesn't work, but leave some feedback!"...

Comment: I leave Windows 11 feedback about lack of features (no toolbars, no proper right context, fat task bar and so on) . I do not know if they are listening but I hope so.